# A UNIX Command to Find the Name of the Student who has the Second Highest Score

Tags: sorting, unix, awk

I am new to Unix Programming. Could you please help me to solve the question.
For example, If the input file has the below content

```
RollNo Name Score
234 ABC 70
567 QWE 12
457 RTE 56
234 XYZ 80
456 ERT 45
```

The output will be

```
ABC
```

I tried something like this

```
sort -k3,3 -rn -t" " | head -n2 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: What commands are you allowed to use? The `tail` command would be useful to get rid of the header line before you sort the data, and head in combination with tail can be used to pick out the *n*th line of the sorted data.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick  tail command also allowed to use.I am tried something above manner (according to my knowledge).could you please help to tell that command.

Comment: Tail outputs the last portion of its input. You can specify the number of lines to output, counting either from the end of the input or from the beginning. Here are some examples that may help. `tail -n +2` will copy the 2nd through last lines of the input to the output. `head -n 4` will output the first 4 lines of the input - you already knew this - but `head -n 4 | tail -n 1` will output just the 4th line of the input. You're already most of the way there; just need to modify your pipeline a bit. Try different things and see what they look like.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk 'NR>1{arr[$3]=$2} END {n=asorti(arr,arr_sorted);  print  arr[arr_sorted[n-1]]}'
```

Demo:

```
$cat file.txt 
RollNo Name Score
234 ABC 70
567 QWE 12
457 RTE 56
234 XYZ 80
456 ERT 45
$awk 'NR>1{arr[$3]=$2} END {n=asorti(arr,arr_sorted);  print  arr[arr_sorted[n-1]]}'  file.txt 
ABC
$
```

Explanation:

`NR>1` --> Skip first record

`{arr[$3]=$2}` --> Create associtive array with marks as index and name as value

`END` <-- read till end of file

`n=asorti(arr,arr_sorted)` <-- Sort array `arr` on index value(i.e marks) and save in `arr_sorted`. `n`= number of element in array

`print  arr[arr_sorted[n-1]]}` <-- `n-1` will point to second last value in arr_sorted (i.e marks) and print corresponding value from `arr`

Comment: Dear @Digvijay,While I am executing above commands it will showing error as "function asorti never defined".How Can I resolve this Error.

Comment: Try using `gawk` instead of `awk`

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is 90% correct just a single change
Try this...it will work.

> sort -k3,3 -rn -t" " | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}'

Instead of using head -n2 replace it with head -n1

Comment: It is not correct because It would print top most scored student but I need second most scored student.