# How to fetch name of student having highest marks in Unix from txt file3?

Tags: unix

This is the `student.txt` file

```
RollNo|Name|Marks
123|Raghu|80
342|Maya|45
561|Gita|56
480|Mohan|71
```

I want to fetch the name of student who has highest.

Comment: Please refer this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61607048/a-unix-command-to-find-the-name-of-the-student-who-has-the-second-highest-score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tail +2 students.txt | awk -F "|" '{print $3 " " $2}' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -d " " -f2`

What it does:

`tail +2` prints the entire file, starting with second line (thus ignore the first line, which is the header).

`awk` separates each line to separate fiels, with the delimiter `"|"` (giving us three column), from which we pick the third and the second columns.

We then `sort` the results, using numeric values (`-n`) that means that 10 is larger than 2. Alphabetically 2 is larger than 10.

We then pick the last line, by calling `tail -1`.

The `cut` command separates the fields with the delimiter " " (`-d " "`), and prints only the name, which is the second field (`-f 2`).